# High-traffic service

Tags: c++, windows, windows-services, ipc

What is the fastest type of inter-process communication on Windows? We need to transfer data with high speed to our "system-wide" scanning component. What's the best type of application for that component? Windows service?

Performance is crucial. Implementation will be developed in C++.

Comment: Please, read the questions first.

Comment: Looks like at least two questions.  What kind of data volume are you talking about (roughly?)

Comment: Yes, they are two. Roughly hundreds of MBs every 10 seconds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your fastest IPC will be shared memory/memory mapped files.  This is done via CreateFileMapping/OpenFileMapping/MapViewOfFile/UnmapViewOfFile and a few other Win32 calls.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366551%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: It should be a system-wide component. Isn't it a problem when we want to have many clients producing data in parallel?